# How to give every co-ordinate another color using tmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, tmap

I am trying to make a map with hotels in las vegas. I have all the coordinates. I also made a map with a dot at the 'hotel points'. But these dots are all black. I need every hotel (dot) to be another color.[image]

As you can see, all the dots (hotels) are black..
This is my code:

```
df_hotels <- df_joinall %>% 
  group_by(hotel_name) 

df <- st_as_sf(df_hotels, coords = c("Longitude","Latitude"))

tmap_mode("view")+

tm_basemap("OpenStreetMap") +

tm_shape(df) +
tm_dots(popup.format = list(text.align = "center"), size = 0.5, alpha = 0.7)
```

Does anyone has suggestions on how to give every point (hotel) another color

Comment: I think you can just add the `col` parameter to `tm_dots`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the points colored you need to map the `col` aesthetic to a column of your data frame. Note that `{tmap}` requires column names enclosed in quotation marks.

Your example is not exactly reproducible, but I expect this to work:

```
df_hotels <- df_joinall %>% 
  group_by(hotel_name) 

df <- st_as_sf(df_hotels, coords = c("Longitude","Latitude"))

tmap_mode("view")+

tm_basemap("OpenStreetMap") +

tm_shape(df) + tm_dots(col = "hotel_name", size = 0.5, alpha = 0.7)
```

Comment: Although my code was not reproducible this is exactly what I needed! This generates some kind of a legend and makes all the different (in this case) hotels another color.